# Help, permutation group prove.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let T be an infinite set and let A(T) be the group of permutation of T, let M={ f belongs to A(T); f(t) is not equal to t for only a finite number of t in T}, prove M is a group.

I am confuse here, I know the identity permutation is the identity of permutation group, but here, f(t) can not equal to t, I feel M does not have identity permutation, what is wrong with me ? and how to do the prove?

Comment: The identity permutation certainly satisfies $id(t) \neq t$ for finitely many $t$. To be precise, it satisfies it for zero $t$...

Comment: @ah11950 Sorry, this is my first second week of studying group, I still don't understand it. I think the identity permutation is f(1)=1, f(2)=2, but here f(t) is not equal to t, what does " id(t)" mean?

Comment: Saying $f(1)=1\ldots$ suggests that $1 \in T$. We don't know what the elements of $T$ are. The identity permutation is just the one which sends $t \mapsto t$ for all $t \in T$. We often denote it by $id$ (short for identity).

Comment: @ah11950 so for identity permutation, id(t)=t, why it is in the M? because M suggest f(t) is not equal to t

Comment: For **finitely many** $t$. If a permutation satisfies $f(t) \neq t$ for no $t$ at all, then it satisfies it for finitely many $t$ - $0$ such $t$, and $0 < \infty$.

Comment: @ah11950 What does " t-0 such t" mean? how to prove this statement?

Comment: $\left|\{t \in T \mid Id(t) \neq t \}\right| = 0$. There is nothing to prove, this is immediate from definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a subset of a group, then you can use the criterion for it to be a subgroup:

1) does it contain the identity?: you have $id \in M$, since it does not move elements (as ah11950 says in his comment);

2) given $f,g \in M$, does $f \circ g \in M$?: Let $A_{f}$ be the set of elements moved by $f$, and $A_{g}$ the one of elements moved by $g$. Then $B=A_{f} \cup A_{g}$ is finite and on $T \setminus B$ the permutation $f \circ g$ fixes all elements;

3) given $f \in M$, does $f^{-1}\in M$?: it is trivial to check that $f^{-1}$ is the identity out of $A_{f}$. Thus $f^{-1} \in M$.

Comment: Could you explain the step 2? Why do we need to let Af and Ag, what do you mean "on T∖B the permutation f∘g fixes all elements?"

Comment: You want to check that $f \circ g \in M$. By definition a generic $h \in M$ if and only if there is a finite set $A_{h}$ such that $h\left( x \right) = x$ for any $x \in T \setminus A_{h}$. According to the expression I used before, now I say "$h$ fixes all elements in $T \setminus A_{h}$", i.e. there it behaves like the identity map. Thus, going back to our $f$ and $g$, we know they have sets $A_{f}$ and $A_{g}$ with this property. To show $f \circ g \in M$ we have to exhibit an $A_{f \circ g}$ with the previous property. You can check you can take $A_{f} \cup A_{g}$.